# Backup drivers for a device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, backup

**If I can't find a driver installer on the internet** when I prep for a reinstall of Windows 7, I figure if the driver is already installed, why not back it up and reinstall later?

The only method I know of is going through Device Manager > Device Properties > Driver Details.

[image]

This gives me a nice list of all the files, **but then I need to go manually retrieve all of them. For devices with a lot of driver files, this is inefficient**.

Is there a **better/faster** way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Your files are stored in 1 of three places.

go to

> %SystemRoot%\System32\

And look for the following directories: Drivers, DriverStore, and DrvStore (may or may not be there).

Also you will want to copy "%systemroot%\inf\".

Copy these directories to some sort of removable media....

Comment: I'd rather not copy **everything** because on some systems the driver store can be massive. But in a jam, I suppose I could do that.

Comment: @Moses - You wouldn't copy everything just the drivers not installed by Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound A) Why? B) How?

Comment: In the screenshot you posted you have two driver files used by your keyboard.  If they were not standard files that were included in Windows you could in theory back them up and transfer them to a new Windows installation.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I can copy/paste all the files manually after finding them, but if I have a device that has 50 driver files, it takes quite a while. I'm looking for a more efficient way to back them up.

Comment: @Moses - You might find it easier to find the installers once and keep media with said installers then to copy driver files.  This leaves you with the task only copying the drivers you don't have an driver installer for.

Answer (score -2):

I recently had to do this, I found a piece of software called DriverMax. Found it very useful when backing up all the drivers for that machine.

Source: http://www.drivermax.com/